# angular js: Unable to add marker in google map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to add a marker in google map but unfortunately, it's not getting added.

There is only one marker in a map.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="gMap">
  <ui-gmap-google-map 
    center='map.center' 
    zoom='map.zoom' aria-label="Google map">

    <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers"
      coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
      <ui-gmap-window>
        <div>{{marker.window.title}}</div>
      </ui-gmap-window>
    </ui-gmap-marker>

  </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

My Angular code looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

myApp.controller("gMap",function($scope){
  $scope.map = { 
    center: { latitude: 39.8282, longitude: -98.5795 }, 
    zoom: 4 
  };

  $scope.markers.id = "1";
  $scope.markers.coords.latitude = "40.7903";
  $scope.markers.coords.longitude = "-73.9597";
  $scope.markers.window.title = "Manhattan New York, NY";

});
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/iamsajeev/pen/vKxVaB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the code a little bit and got the result.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

myApp.controller("gMap",function($scope){
  $scope.map = { 
    center: { latitude: 39.8282, longitude: -98.5795 }, 
    zoom: 4 
  };

  $scope.marker = { 
    coords: { latitude: 39.8282, longitude: -98.5795 }, 
    id: 4 ,
    window: { title: "Manhattan New York, NY" }
  };


});
```

AND HTML became:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="gMap">
  <ui-gmap-google-map 
    center='map.center' 
    zoom='map.zoom' aria-label="Google map">

    <ui-gmap-marker 
      coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
      <ui-gmap-window>
        <div>{{marker.window.title}}</div>
      </ui-gmap-window>
    </ui-gmap-marker>

  </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/iamsajeev/pen/vKxVaB)

Answer (score 1):

change the controller to:

```
myApp.controller("gMap",function($scope){
  $scope.map = { 
    center: { latitude: 39.8282, longitude: -98.5795 }, 
    zoom: 4 
  };

  $scope.markers = [];
  $scope.marker = {
    id: 1,
    coords: {
      latitude: "40.7903",
      longitude: "-73.9597",
    },
    window: {
      title: "Manhattan New York, NY",
    }
  };
  $scope.markers.push($scope.marker);
});
```

Why?

`markers` is an array in your HTML. In the controller you didn't declare it.

`marker` instead is an object.

You could create now more markers and push it to the `markers` to show more than one point in the map with `$scope.markers.push($scope.otherMarker);`

Comment: Sorry my answer is for more than one marker, even if works just for one

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. Just added the `markers` array on which there's a `ng-repeat`

Here's a working codePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxpaqE